# Oracle Java Virtual Machine install?

Tags: java, software-installation

I cant get it install and I need it running for a job application i need to put in online.

```
jre-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

that's the file and every time I try to install it wont complete, says cannot find file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
```

This will install Oracle JVM and will update it when needed.

But if you want to install JVM manually, you should use these commands:

```
tar -xzf jre-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
sudo mv jre1.7.0_51/ /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_51
```

Then run

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java
```

and

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java    1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/ia32-java-6-sun/jre/bin/java   63        manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java    1061      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java        63        manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java       4         manual mode  

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Follow the instructions on screen. Your numbers would be quite different from mine.

Comment: The ppa method works for me, but with the manual installation I get the warning `update-alternatives: --install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority>` and it exits.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have Java 7, follow this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

Oracle java is better than the openjdk in terms of performance IMO

Comment: That is a lie! OpenJDK's source code is used to make Oracle Java, so they're both just as fast. If anything, OpenJDK is faster because it gets patches from the open source community (which may affect speed) before they get implemented into Oracle Java.

Answer (score 1):

Now the commands should be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update #(skip this line for Ubuntu 18.04)
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

oracle-java8-set-default will be installed automatically on Ubuntu. For other OSes, the last line should be

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo apt-get` procedures don't currently work due to changes at Oracle. @Danatela had the best answer that worked for me. There is only one change to using his `sudo update-alternatives --install` command.

The command should include a priority value at the end so is looks like `--install <link> <name> <path> <priority>`

I updated the current JDK (complete file is jdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz) in the following command:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/java/jdk-12.0.2_51/bin/java 1`

where link = `/user/bin/java`, name = `java`, path = `/usr/lib/java/jdk-12.0.2_51/bin/java`, and priority = `1` (auto)